# concatenating string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-concatenation

Is there a way in SQL sever that can write the output as follow:

```
select events
  from mytable
```

original output

```
events
--------
123456
894531
985233
829292
920202
392939
299223
```

desired output

```
'123456', '894531','985233','829292','920202','392939','299223'
```

select '' + CustomerID + ','
from dbo.Customers
customerid
ALFKI,
ANATR,
ANTON,
AROUT,
BERGS,

Would like to see the result as
customerid
'ALFKI',
'ANATR',
'ANTON',
'AROUT',
'BERGS',
so on...

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT
  STUFF(
    (SELECT
      ', ' + events
     FROM dbo.mytable
     FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') As concatenated_string
```

If you want the values enclosed in single quotes then edit the padding above.

Comment: The third argument to the STUFF function should be 2, not 1. Small point, but otherwise there is a leading space.

Comment: Just ran the query. It does work! but the result does not show the single quotation as wanted. not sure why. Many thanks!

Comment: Am I the only one who's been seeing this type of *same* questions and answers over and over?

Comment: @SungMaister: The thing is this is quite common thing to do in SQL but there's no implicit support for it (as is in MySql for instance). No wonder so many people ask this question over and over...

Answer (score 3):

[Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) discusses the various options you have, like recursive CTE, blackbox XML (like Mitch' solution), CLR, cursors, recursive scalar UDFs etc etc, as well as some unreliable but fast approaches (SELECT with variable concatenation).