# single quotation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [concatenating string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019942/concatenating-string)

I posted a similar question earlier and asked about using SQL server to output the result with a single quote. Could someone edcuate me please?

```
select ' ' + CustomerID + ',' 
  from dbo.Customers 

customerid 
------------
ALFKI, 
ANATR, 
ANTON, 
AROUT, 
BERGS,
```

Would like to see the result as

```
customerid 
-----------
'ALFKI', 
'ANATR', 
'ANTON', 
'AROUT', 
'BERGS',
```

so on...

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019942/concatenating-string

Comment: Please clarify in your original question that you want the single quotes, don't post a new question about it.

Comment: Will do it next time, OMG Ponies. Thanks very much all

Answer (score 1):

```
select '''' + CustomerID + ''',' 
  from dbo.Customers
```